# about unlocking excel file

Tags: excel

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

I have an excel file with protection, I need to unlock the file

I tried every way but didn't work. Please if anyone know a way to unlock it help me out.

Comment: Just google "unprotect/unlock/remove password Excel file online"

Comment: Do you know the password or you stole the file ??

Comment: please explain what exactly you've tried and what happened (any error message received?) Without that we really can't help.

Comment: i have bought a program called pass fab for excel and it has been about a mont and couldnt find the password.ever one giving diffrent ways to unlock it.but ı m not good at computer.if anyone can help i can send the file.i will be greatfull if anyone help.thanks.

Comment: What? The program tries to crack the password by guessing? Excelfiles are really easy to crack. You just unzip them and edit the sheet/workbook file, or upload them to a service that does it for you. It's really simple

Comment: hi Andreas, i tried many times but didnt work the way you sed.pls if you can you do it for me.if you can help let me know i will send you the file.thanku very much.